# What is the physical interpretation of root mean squared speed?

Tags: thermodynamics

I understand that the average molecular speed is the speed that all the molecules have if the speed was distributed equally, but what is the intuition or physical interpretation behind the root mean squared speed?

Comment: *I understand that the average molecular speed is the speed that all the molecules have if the speed was distributed equally, but what is the intuition or physical interpretation behind the root mean squared speed?* $\Rightarrow$ the **root mean square** molecular speed is the speed that all the molecules have if the speed **squared** was distributed equally.

Comment: Yes, I understand that fact. However, my question was in regards to the interpretation of such a fact. The speed of a particle is the average distance it covers in a unit time, and it's easy to understand such a thing. Not so much with speed squared, what is the physical manifestation of such an idea? Of course, as the answer-er mentioned, it is related to the average kinetic energy! I just had a bit of a mental lapse is all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RMS speed is related to the *mean kinetic energy*.

See, kinetic energy is $T = \frac{1}{2}mv^2$, so assuming a single species gas (meaning all the masses are the same) the mean kinetic energy is
\begin{align*}
\left< T \right> 
&= \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N T_i \\
&= \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{1}{2} m v_i^2 \\
&= \frac{1}{2} m \left( \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N v_i^2\right) \;.
\end{align*}

Then writing $v_a = \sqrt{2T_a/m}$ for the speed associated with some kinetic energy we find that the speed associated with the mean kinetic energy is
\begin{align*}
v_\text{mean kinetic energy} 
&= \sqrt{\frac{2\left<T\right>}{m}} \\
&= \sqrt{\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N v_i^2} \;,
\end{align*}
which is exactly the RMS speed distribution of the molecules you started with
$$ v_\text{mean kinetic energy} = v_\text{RMS} \;.$$

So, the RMS speed is the one that gives one of those particles the mean kinetic energy of the particles in the sample.

Comment: That makes sense. I just had a bit of an illogical moment there - my line of reasoning was that if all the particles has the same average speed, then they would have the same kinetic energy as the mean kinetic energy, which obviously isn't true. The kinetic energy of a particle with the mean speed is not necessarily the same as the mean kinetic energy. Thanks.